# Postgresql WITH RECURSIVE COPY TO

Tags: postgresql

In a WITH RECURSIVE query, is it possible to to use COPY TO in the same way INSERT INTO?

I'm trying to write a file from a recursive query without having to save it to a table first.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sure why not, eg:

```
t=# copy ( WITH RECURSIVE t(n) AS (
    VALUES (1)
  UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1 FROM t WHERE n < 100
)
SELECT sum(n) FROM t) to '/tmp/rc';
COPY 1
Time: 5.161 ms
t=# \! cat /tmp/rc
5050
```

Comment: I think the OP *might* be trying to use the `COPY` *inside* the CTE. But if not, this is a decent attempt to answer a very vague question.

Comment: hm... in that case it would take dynamic plpgsql I guess... but then why CTE?.. Well - lets see what OP says :) good point though - I reread the OP - yes it definetely might be the request